# Error While Deleting row from multiple dependent tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

ERROR: syntax error at or near "r"
Query was:
Delete r,ur from un_received_compansation_reason ur join received_compensation_info r on received_compensation_info.compensation_info_id = un_received_compansation_reason.compensation_info_id where compensation_info_id=2

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  More specifically for query questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specific table aliases, so try writing the query as:

```
Delete r, ur
    from un_received_compansation_reason ur join 
         received_compensation_info r 
         on r.compensation_info_id = ur.compensation_info_id 
where r.compensation_info_id = 2;
```

Comment: [CompletionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ERROR: syntax error at or near "r"
  Position: 8 Query was:
Delete r, ur from un_received_compansation_reason ur join received_compensation_info r  on r.compensation_info_id = ur.compensation_info_id  where r.compensation_info_id = '1'

]

Comment: Still getting the error

Comment: @JayantChaudhary . . . The question looks like valid MySQL to me.  I suspect the problem is with your interface.  One possible issue is a bad character in the string, but it may simply be that your interface doesn't accept this type of query.

Comment: ohkk..so what can i do rectify this kind of problem

Comment: String Compensation_del_query = "delete unrec,rec"+
            " from un_received_compansation_reason unrec join"+
             " received_compensation_info rec "+
            "on rec.compensation_info_id = unrec.compensation_info_id "+
           "where compensation_info_id = "+Deletion_comp_Id+"";

Comment: SqlUpdate comp_del=  Ebean.createSqlUpdate(Compensation_del_query);
            comp_del.execute();

Comment: this is my code can u spot some kind of prob here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use table aliases in time joining key like below

```
Delete r,ur from un_received_compansation_reason ur join 
received_compensation_info r on 
r.compensation_info_id = ur.compensation_info_id 
where ur.compensation_info_id=2
```

Comment: [CompletionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ERROR: syntax error at or near "r"
  Position: 8 Query was:
Delete r, ur from un_received_compansation_reason ur join received_compensation_info r on r.compensation_info_id = ur.compensation_info_id where r.compensation_info_id = 2

Still the error is same.

Comment: String Compensation_del_query = "delete unrec,rec"+ " from un_received_compansation_reason unrec join"+ " received_compensation_info rec "+ "on rec.compensation_info_id = unrec.compensation_info_id "+ "where compensation_info_id = "+Deletion_comp_Id+""

Comment: SqlUpdate comp_del= Ebean.createSqlUpdate(Compensation_del_query); comp_del.execute();

Comment: this is my code can u spot some kind of prob here